# How can I write C for loop in VHDL-AMS?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to write a code in VHDL-AMS for below for-loop in C.

```
for (i=0; i<m; i*=k)
```

In the above example I incremented in particular steps `i = i*k". I am not able to find a solution for this in VHDL-AMS.

Comment: I think you'll need to use a `while` instead.

Comment: Given the properties of multiplication by zero, this should optimise nicely, the VHDL equivalent is `loop ... end loop;` Unless the loop modifies m, in which case `while m > 0 loop ... end loop;`

Answer (score 2):

In VHDL `for` loops behave a little differently to those in C. Unlike in C, where maths is done on a loop variable (`i` in your example), in VHDL a `for` loop steps over each value in a `range`. Usually, the loop variable in VHDL will be an `integer`, so you can step over each value in an integer range. But you have to step over *every* value - you can't miss them out.

So, how to solve your problem? One way is to use a `while` loop as has been suggested; another is to use a `for` loop, but to loop over an integer range and do some calculation on the loop variable. So, in VHDL you can do:

```
for some_other_variable in some_minimum to some_maximum loop
  i :=  -- some function of your some_other_variable
  -- the rest of your code within the loop
end loop;
```

VHDL-AMS is a superset of VHDL-93, so it is reasonable to assume the `for` loops behave in the same way.

Comment: This doesn't actually implement the same loop ( i * k to some power), and could be strength-reduced to a simple addition `i := i + k;`

Comment: @BrianDrummond You're right - it isn't the same, is it? Given the start of `i=0`, the example in the OP would just loop forever!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for loop, if `m` is a multiple of `k`.  For example:

```
for i in 0 to (m/k)-1 loop
  -- j = 0, k, 2k, ...
  j := i*k;
  ...
  -- Do something with j
  ...
end loop;
```

Now, even if `m` isn't a multiple of `k`, you can work around it with:

```
for i in 0 to integer(ceil(real(m)/real(k)))-1 loop
  -- j = 0, k, 2k, ...
  j := i*k;
  ...
  -- Do something with j
  ...
end loop;
```

Of course this assumes `m` and `k` have static ranges (i.e. not signals).

Comment: Thank you for your help.